# Faster way to iterate through if a string contains a phrase from array list?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm iterating my string through an array of phrases with this code:

```
public boolean checkName(String nameInputed, ArrayList<String> phraseList) {
    
    boolean match = false;        
    for (String phrase : phraseList) {
        if (nameInputed.matches(".*" + phrase + ".*")) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return match ;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a faster way to check with a large list of phrases.

Comment: Method [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) in class `java.lang.String`?

Comment: I didn't know that exists haha, I'll try it out.

Comment: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/index.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about...

```
public boolean checkName(String nameInputed, java.util.List<String> phraseList) {
    return phraseList.stream()
                     .filter(phrase -> nameInputed.contains(phrase))
                     .findFirst()
                     .isPresent();
}
```

And if you don't want to use [stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html) then how about...

```
public boolean checkName(String nameInputed, java.util.List<String> phraseList) {
    for (String phrase : phraseList) {
        if (nameInputed.contains(phrase)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

### Edit

As @user16320675 suggested in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71508829/faster-way-to-iterate-through-if-a-string-contains-a-phrase-from-array-list/71508926#comment126389473_71508926)

```
public boolean checkName(String nameInputed, java.util.List<String> phraseList) {
    return phraseList.stream()
                     .anyMatch(phrase -> nameInputed.contains(phrase));
}
```

Comment: stream worked wonders for my code, thanks!